# Memory usage: Program allocates too much memory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory-management, gdb

I have coded a program in C++ for Ubuntu Server (64-Bit) which should run 24/7. The Server has 2GB RAM, but apparently my program is allocating too much memory.

This is the output of `top` after about 2 hours

```
top - 13:35:57 up  1:39,  1 user,  load average: 0.15, 0.13, 0.08
Tasks:  68 total,   2 running,  66 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.9 us,  5.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.3 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   2050048 total,   540852 used,  1509196 free,    34872 buffers
KiB Swap:  1509372 total,        0 used,  1509372 free.    93060 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  902 root      20   0 1019896 364920   4492 S 13.1 17.8  13:07.03 Bether
```

How you can see my code already consumes 17.8% memory. At some point, the server will crash because it has no memory left.

My problem is that the program should not do that, but I can't find out where the memory gets allocated and not free'd anymore. Is there a tool, maybe even inside `gdb`, to find out where the program allocates the most memory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is more related to programming than to administration! Anyway, you can try `valgrind` to see if you have a memory leak.

Comment: Yes I was not really sure where to put it. I'll have a look at valgrind, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), it should be in the Ubuntu repository. it can give you detailed information about memory usage in C++ programs. Kind of like a debugger for memory usage.

`valgrind --tool=memcheck <your_app> <your_apps_params>`

Also check out [ccmalloc](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/ccmalloc/), [NJAMD](http://fscked.org/projects/njamd), [LeakTracer](http://www.andreasen.org/LeakTracer/)